# Smallest possible dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $A$ is $3\times 4$ matrix in which the nullity is less than $3$, and consider the linear mapping $f(v)=Av$. What is the smallest possible dimension for the set of all vectors $f(v)$, where $v$ is any vector in the domain?

So the nullity can be $0,1,2$. The maximum dimension of the domain is $4$ because there are $4$ columns.

The dimension of domain is the rank plus the nullity so $4 = r + 2$ or rank is $2$.

Is my way of solving this correct? Additionally is the dimension of the domain the number of columns or is it just the smaller of the rows and columns?

Comment: Hi new user. Welcome! You might like to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, 2 is the correct answer. The Dim(Domain) is the dimension of the domain space, which for a linear transformation corresponds to the number of columns in the matrix (you are going from R4 to R3). You can think about the problem intuitively as follows: you start out with 4 dimensions, you lose at most 2 dimensions (that is the nullity), so you are left with at least $4-2=2$ dimensions still alive.